# Java - Display relative path to a root directory

Tags: java, path

I am writing a small `Java` program to list files in a root directory recursively. This is the code I used.

```
public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            displayDirectoryContents(file);
        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File currentDir = new File("root-direcotry");
    displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
}
```

The result I got is something like:

```
root-direcotry/1.txt
root-direcotry/2.txt
root-direcotry/t1/a.txt
root-direcotry/t2/b.txt
root-direcotry/t4/c.txt
```

My question is can I just display the relative path without the "*root-direcotry*"?

i.e. What I want to achieve is displaying:

```
/1.txt
/2.txt
/t1/a.txt
/t2/b.txt
/t4/c.txt
```

I prefer not using any `String` method to just not display that part.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir, String rootDir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            displayDirectoryContents(file, rootDir);
        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getPath().replaceFirst(rootDir, ""));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String rootDir = <rootDir>;
    File currentDir = new File(rootDir);
    displayDirectoryContents(currentDir, rootDir);
}
```

Comment: What if a subdirectory is named "root-direcotry"?

Comment: @JBNizet it is the placeholder that the OP used for root directory as you can see in the question.

Comment: You didn't understand. Imagine `rootDir` is initialized with "foo". And imagine the foo directory contains `foo/foo/foo/foo.txt`. Now imagine rootDir is initialized with `/` (because you want to display everything under the root directory). Your code will fail in both of these cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as @JBNizer pointed out, using `replace` may lead to the problem when two files/dirs have the same name.

Comment: @Gisonrg Can you give me an example?

Comment: @JBNizet Now I understood what you meen. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @Gisonrg Now I understood what you meen. I have corrected my answer.